# GridView Grouping from c sharp

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I have a requirement where I have to display Different Views .i.e Grouping and non grouping list. I used GridView.

I have two list from view model one is Direct list for Non Grouping View and other is Group of lists for Grouping View.

```
Lst_Videos = List<VideoItem> - For Non Grouping View

Lst_grp = List<VideoGrp> - For Grouping View

public Class VideoGrp
{

public string Key { get; set; }
public int ItemsCount { get; set; }

public List<VideoItem> Items { get; set; }

}

public Class VideoItem
{

public string MediaId { get; set; }

public string PictureTitle { get; set; }
}
```

In XXAML i have only one GridView. First I Display Grouped View

```
 <Grid >
     <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="MainGrps" ItemsPath="Items" IsSourceGrouped="True" />
      </Grid.Resources>

     <GridView x:Name="SharedGriidViewUI" ItemsSource="{Binding  Source={StaticResource MainGrps}}"  
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItmTemplateTimeLine}">
         <GridView.GroupStyle>
             <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="False" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HdrTemplateTimeLine}"/>
         </GridView.GroupStyle>
      </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
MainGrps.Source = Lst_grp;
```

It Works absolutely fine.

Now I want to switch to other View on clicking the app bar button. So I did like this

```
private void AppBarButton_Click_List(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainGrps.Source = null;
        MainGrps.ItemsPath = null;
        SharedGriidViewUI.ItemsSource = null;

        MainGrps.Source = ((ExtraPageViewModel)this.DataContext).Lst_Videos ;
        SharedGriidViewUI.ItemsSource = MainGrps.Source;
        SharedGriidViewUI.ItemTemplate = ItmTemplateList;
    }
```

This also Works Fine.

Now on Click of AppBarButton I want to display Grouped View again. I did like this

```
private void AppBarButton_Click_TimeLine(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainGrps.Source = null;
        SharedGriidViewUI.ItemsSource = null;

        MainGrps.Source = ((ExtraPageViewModel)this.DataContext).Lst_Grp;
        MainGrps.ItemsPath = new PropertyPath("Items");
        SharedGriidViewUI.ItemsSource = MainGrps.Source;
        SharedGriidViewUI.ItemTemplate = ItmTemplateTimeLine;
    }
```

Now I am not able to see the List. I get Binding error exceptions.

Error: BindingExpression path error: 'MediaId' property not found on 'Qts.Models.TimeLineGoup

Error: BindingExpression path error: 'PictureTitle' property not found on 'Qts.Models.TimeLineGoup
That means The Xaml this time expecting the PictureTitle and MediaID in Grp Direct instead of Items property in the group.

So please tell me Where I am wrong. How I need to bind group from cs file.  Please suggest or help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks and Regards Sunil Kumar S C

Comment: Instead of changing the items source and other properties of the GridView you could have 2 grid views and set their visibility on the Click events. I think performace wise it shouldn't be worse than what you are doing now.

Comment: Hey Considering Two Grid Views and that too playing with Visibility is more worst I believe beacuse CollectionViewSource is not a UI element its a resource property. Anyhow thanks

Answer (score 0):

got it working.
 I changed MainGrps.Source to MainGrps.Source.View;
 Worked like charm.

MainGrps.Source = ((ExtraPageViewModel)this.DataContext).Lst_Grp;
SharedGriidViewUI.ItemsSource = MainGrps.Source.View;